# Recoil Async Selector does not work with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recoiljs

I tried to use recoil selector which includes async functions in my Next.js project.

However, **the page keeps displaying a fallback and does not render Component.**
Recoil Async Selector does not return values even when async function is finished.

Sample Code below:

```tsx
// page.tsx

"use client"
import * as React from "react"
import { RecoilRoot, useRecoilValue } from "recoil"
import { textToDisplay } from "./recoil"

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        <SomeComponent />
      </React.Suspense>
    </RecoilRoot>
  )
}

const SomeComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const text = useRecoilValue(textToDisplay);

  return (
    <h1>{text}</h1>
  )
}
```

```ts
// recoil.ts

import { atom, selector } from "recoil";

export const textState = atom<string>({
    key: "TEXT_ATOM_KEY",
    default: "atom",
})

export const textToDisplay = selector({
    key: "TEXT_SELECTOR_KEY",
    get: async ({ get }) => {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        const text = get(textState);
        return text + " selector";
    }
})
```

CodeSandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cool-mopsa-t3zmx9

(if the problem is not reproducible, click "Restart Task" in "Start Dev Server")

Any solution here?

Comment: Hey I have the same issue, have you solved your problem? I'm so desperated

Comment: Did you try useRecoilValueLoadable instead of useRecoilValue?

Comment: @IkhyeonKim I decided to use Jotai instead of Recoil. Jotai works well in this situatoin.

Comment: @Mearaj Thank you for your comment! Using `useRecoilValueLoadable` works well.  But the document says we don't have to use `useRecoilValueLoadable` and we just need `useRecoilValue` (https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/asynchronous-data-queries#asynchronous-example). I was very confused due to it.

Comment: Hi @F.Yuja, if you are using async function in selector and atom functions, then you should use useRecoilValueLoadable. Otherwise other option is to use ErrorBoundary and Suspense. They have mentioned in the docs I remember. If you can't find it in the docs, please let me know I will find and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own useAsyncRecoilValue hook to deal with async cases like this. It's syntactic sugar around the `useRecoilValueLoadable` hook as previous comments have mentioned. I prefer using this method because it prevents a flash of content whilst the data is loading.

```
export const useAsyncRecoilValue = <T>(state: RecoilValueReadOnly<T>) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState<T | null>(null);

  const loadable = useRecoilValueLoadable(state);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadable.state === 'hasValue') {
      setData(loadable.contents);
    }
  }, [loadable]);

  return data;
};
```

Then replace all instances of `useRecoilValue` with `useAsyncRecoilValue`. There should be no need to use Suspense with this method.